# any option to create the bucket with Glacier storage class? using duplicity

Tags: amazon-s3

any option to create the bucket with Glacier storage class?  using duplicity and linux command.

Please give more details.  Right now uploaded with standard class in AWS s3

AWS Create bucket with Glacier storage.

example code for aws s please